# Terminology for set of infinite strings with a certain prefix

Tags: terminology, formal-languages, symbolic-dynamics, combinatorics-on-words

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a finite alphabet, and let $C$ be the Cantor space $\mathcal{A}^\omega$ under the product topology.

Given a finite string $s \in \mathcal{A}^*$, let $C(s)$ be the set of all strings in $\mathcal{A}^\omega$ that have $s$ as a prefix.

Is there a standard name for such sets $C(s)$ in $C$?  If we think of $C$ as a Cantor set, then $C(s)$ is one the canonical "Cantor subsets".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $C(s)$ is an example of a [cylinder set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_set).

More specifically, $C(s)$ is called a **basic open cylinder** (since other cylinder sets are 
unions of such sets). See e.g. Andre Nies' monograph *Computability and Randomness*; the notation $[s]$ is used for $C(s)$.

Comment: In Kechris' book the notation  $N_s $ is used, but no name for it is assigned there. This applies to any countable power.

Comment: Indeed. Also, since a cylinder is shift-invariant, this is a very common object in symbolic dynamics.

Comment: If one uses an arbitrary countable power $A^X$ and call cylinder any subset of the form $\{f\in A^X:f|_F=g\}$ (for finite $F\subset X$ and $g\in A^F$), one gets something more general, since here $F$ is assumed to be an initial segment of $\omega$. I'm not sure which definition of cylinder is more common (of course I rather like the latter one).